# Can't connect to MongoDB via mongoose when testing through postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodemon

I can't connect to mongoDB via Postman to make any requests...

I'm getting this in my console:

```
    [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
    API Server Listening on port 8080!
```

Here is my app.js:

````
```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const api = require('./api')
    const morgan = require('morgan') // logger
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const cors = require('cors')

    app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080))

    app.use(bodyParser.json)    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }))

    app.use(cors())

    app.use('/api', api)
    app.use(express.static('static'))

    app.use(morgan('dev'))

    app.use(function (req, res) {
        const err = new Error('Not Found')
        err.status = 404
        res.json(err)
    })

    // Add MongoDB connection and mongoose
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/globomantics', {
        useNewUrlParser: true, //deprecated url parser
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })

    const db = mongoose.connection
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
    db.once('open', function () {
        app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
            console.log('API Server Listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '!')
        })
    })
```
````

All I'm getting from postman is:

```
    There was an error connecting to http://localhost:8080/api/user/?ObjectId=5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98.
```

Here is the api folder structure:

```
    API>
       routes>
           User>
           Transaction>
       index.js
```

**ALSO - i'm following a pluralsight tutorial it might be that the packages are old i'm looking through package.json - but i'm comletely lost**

**api/user**

```
    const User = require('../../models/user')
    module.exports = function (router) {
          router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
            User.findById(req.params.id).exec()
              .then(docs => res.status(200)
                .json(docs))
              .catch(err => res.status(500)
                .json({
                  message: 'Error finding user',
                  error: err
                }))
          })

          router.get('/user/email/:email', function (req, res) {
            User.find({ 'email': req.params.email }).exec()
              .then(docs => res.status(200)
                .json(docs))
              .catch(err => res.status(500)
                .json({
                  message: 'Error finding user',
                  error: err
                }))
          })

          router.post('/user', function (req, res) {
            let user = new User(req.body)
            user.save(function (err, user) {
              if (err) return console.log(err)
              res.status(200).json(user)
            })
          })

          router.put('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
            console.log(req.body)
            let qry = { _id: req.params.id }
            let doc = {
              // first: req.body.firstName,
              // last: req.body.lastName,
              // email: req.body.email,
              // password: req.body.password,
              isActive: req.body.isActive
            }
            console.log(doc)
            User.update(qry, doc, function (err, respRaw) {
              if (err) return console.log(err)
              res.status(200).json(respRaw)
            })
          })
        }
```

**API/transaction**

```
const Transaction = require('../../models/transaction')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')

    module.exports = function (router) {
      // Get transactions for given year and month, by userId...
      router.get('/transaction/:year/:month', function (req, res) {
        const userId = req.get('userId')
        const month = req.params.month - 1 // JS months are zero-based
        const year = req.params.year
        const startDt = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0))
        const endDt = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month + 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

        const qry = {
          userId: userId,
          transactionDate: {
            $gte: startDt,
            $lt: endDt
          }
        }

        Transaction.find(qry)
          .sort({ 'transactionDate': 1 })
          .exec()
          .then(docs => res.status(200)
            .json(docs))
          .catch(err => res.status(500)
            .json({
              message: 'Error finding transactions for user',
              error: err
            }))
      })    


      // Get transactions running balance for a specific user...
      router.get('/transaction/balance/:year/:month', function (req, res) {
        const userId = req.get('userId')
        const month = req.params.month - 1 // JS months are zero-based
        const year = req.params.year
        const endDt = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1))
        const pipeline = [
          {
            $match: {
              userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
            }
          },
          {
            $match: {
              transactionDate: { $lt: endDt }
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: null,
              charges: { $sum: '$charge' },
              deposits: { $sum: '$deposit' }
            }
          }
        ]

        Transaction.aggregate(pipeline).exec()
          .then(docs => res.status(200)
            .json(docs))
          .catch(err => res.status(500)
            .json({
              message: 'Error finding transactions for user',
              error: err
            }))
      })

      // Create new transaction document
      router.post('/transaction', function (req, res) {
        let transaction = new Transaction(req.body)
        transaction.save(function (err, transaction) {
          if (err) return console.log(err)
          res.status(200).json(transaction)
        })
      })
    }
```

**API/indexjs**

```
       const express = require('express')
       const router = express.Router()

       require('./routes/transaction')(router)
       require('./routes/user')(router)

       module.exports = router
```

Comment: The route is defined as `/user/:id` so change the request URL without the query string (ObjectId etc.) to this `http://localhost:8080/api/user/5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98`

Comment: i've tried this with both users and transactions and keep getting nothing back

Comment: Well, with the route defined as such this is the way you should be making the request. Is the reuqest reaching the route controller (try a console there)? I would suggest to define a route at topmost API/index.js level and then go down from there one by one (makes debugging easier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably because the route you're trying to access is not defined by you. Please check if you have defined this `POST` route in your API or not.

`http://localhost:8080/api/user/?ObjectId=5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98.`

This error can also occur if your route is defined properly but when you execute the code defined in the route, your server crashes due to unhandled error. If possible, paste your code from `api.js` here.

Comment: Are you making a `GET` or a `POST` request through postman? If you're making a `GET` request then you need to define that route as `app.get('/user',(..)=>{..})` inside `api/user.js` and get query parameters as `let ObjectId = req.query.ObjectId;`. If you're making a `POST` request then I think there's an error occurring in your `POST` route `app.post('/user',(..)=>{..})` inside `api/user.js` in which case your server crashes and couldn't send back a response to postman which leads to an error. Check your terminal for errors after you hit submit from postman. Post that error here, if possible.

Comment: this is a GET request. I've got this as the route: 


 `router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id).exec()
      .then(docs => res.status(200)
        .json(docs))
      .catch(err => res.status(500)
        .json({
          message: 'Error finding user',
          error: err
        }))
  })`

Comment: I think `app.get('/user/:id',(..)=>{..})` route cannot handle(or capture) the URL that you've given: `http://localhost:8080/api/user/?ObjectId=5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98`. For this, you need `app.get('/user',(..)=>{..})` route and get query parameters as `let ObjectId = req.query.ObjectId;`. Please do a `console.log('here')` to make sure your route is actually handling the URL that you provided.

Comment: Ajay, I'm getting the same thing - also, i'm not getting anything from morgan in the terminal it's like the request isn't going through at all. 

postman console: 
GET http://localhost:8080/api/user/5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98
Error: read ECONNRESET

Comment: with a different id i get this from postman - GET http://localhost:8080/api/user/5a777f0a75f64a1698221d98
Error: socket hang up

Comment: Since I'm not able to reproduce the error myself, I cannot debug it and hence not able to help any further. I'm clueless right now. If you have this code open-sourced, please provide a suitable GitHub link so that I can reproduce the error myself and debug it.

Comment: Ajay - seriously, thank you so much. - https://github.com/iuriikogan/business-app.git

Comment: Yea I understand. So I tried your code and found the issue. You have this line `app.use(bodyParser.json);` in your code which actually should be `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. Also, your code in the given GitHub link mentions that you're using `3000` as port but in the code given above you're making the request on `8080` port. Please rectify the port number. Try it and let me know if you still have any error left.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
db.once('open', function () {
   console.log('connection Opened ')
})
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
   console.log('API Server Listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '!')
})
```

instead of

```
db.once('open', function () {
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('API Server Listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '!')
 })
})
```

because it seems your server is not listening , even after logging `API Server Listening on port 8080!`

Comment: Thank you, that gives me both the logs in the console but the same result! :-(

Answer (score 0):

app.js - 10

app.use(bodyParser.json) should be app.use(bodyParser.json())